# My smart bulb is randomly flashing. Is it dying?

Tags: lighting, led

Here's the thing. I've had this cheap Smart Wi-Fi LED light bulb for over a year and I have to say that it worked pretty good until now. I recently changed my ISP and they gave me a new router, so I obviously had to reconfigure my Smart Bulb function on the new network and then the weird stuff started. When turned OFF from any device (and for device I mean my phone/google assistant, not the wall switch), the light starts throwing a periodic flash every 3 minutes give or take, and it's not a weak flash, I'm talking about a 1/4 second full brightness flash, powerful enough so that you can see it with your eyes closed when trying to sleep. When turned on it has like the opposite behavior, one solid flicker every 3 min. I thought I could get used to it or that it was a temporary issue with the new router but it's been over a week and it's kinda driving me nuts. I've seen a lot of people online complain about their LED bulbs flickering when off but they describe a soft, nearly perceptible flicker, nothing like what I described above.
Sorry if this has already been answered but I searched for quite a while and couldn't find anything.

Do any of you guys have any idea about what might be going on? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it happened right after the change, and due to the symptoms, it seems that it must be related to your new router. You'll find better answers in a software forum.

Comment: That sounds really annoying. I doubt it's dying though, seems more like a software bug. Some smart light bulbs have an option for a factory reset, I'd first try that. There's also an possibility that your smart light bulb has an update available from the manufacturer. If that also doesn't solve your problem then I'd try it on a different network. That would let you easily exclude you router as the problem.

Comment: Reason #479.5 to buy your own router/access points and decline your ISPs equipment... - Meanwhile, since the problem is with the "smart" bulb (and presumably its network connection or the like) your question would need to detail exactly what brand and model it is, not generically describe it as "cheap Smart Wi-Fi LED light bulb" to have a hope of anyone being able to help. I'm fond of dumb bulbs with dumb switches that just work, but if you want to have to upgrade your lightbulb's firmware or reset its networking, you're going to have to give details.

Comment: the description of the flashing sounds like a status message or an alert ... does the bulb have an embedded web server?

Comment: Hey guys, sorry for the delayed answer. In response to some of your questions:
The device's only label says Powercase A95BU22-8 22W. I found no info on the brand, and the model name took me into some odd, Chinese online shopping pages that apparently sell similar models. Also I've been playing some more with it and I noticed that the issue must be something with the router that the ISP gave me, like you said. Anyway, I have to buy another router since this one's configuration is completely blocked, so that might do the trick.
Thanks a lot for answering, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I wanna try and see if I can build my own controller with Arduino, might be fun to tinker with that. What do you think?

Comment: Mostly unrelated, but unless you believe the password to be compromised, I always recommend setting up a new router with the same network name and password to avoid needing reconfiguration. Too late for this here though.

Comment: As you say Arduino - a lot of these lamps are "hackable" - in the sense that you can install a modified or open source firmware on them. This way, you bypass the random chinese server the lamp is constantly connected and all the possible things that can go wrong with this connection.

Comment: Is it Morse code? Maybe Russian hackers?

Answer (score 0):

I’m just going to throw this out there, because it reminds me of my amazon echo device, when I changed routers and kept the same echo the amazon echo wouldn’t work even though I used the same user and passphrase to connect it, it never   crossed my mind that every device usually has a cache to remember what to connect to ( 2 way communication ) without asking for the credentials each time, part of that cache being the old IPv4/IPv6 credentials, so I just bought a new one and it worked, go figure.

I helped someone install a smart bulb a few weeks ago and the reset function is embedded in my brain, literally. because we reset the smart bulb 10+ times because we were impatient on it updating in the background and then reconnecting. To reset a smart bulb it should be as simple as turning the light switch on and off ten times in a row, the tenth time it’ll blink telling you it’s ready and clear.